# unresolved external symbol with glib and VS C++

Tags: c, visual-c++

Compiling FluidSynth 1.1.1 from source. I have unresolved external symbol with glib, using Visual C++ Express 2010, how do I actually link the glib.lib correctly in the IDE? Do I need wsock libraries as well?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: fluidsynth_dll, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: fluidsynth_lib, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth_dll\.\Release\fluidsynth_dll.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(992,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(fluidsynth_dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (fluidsynth). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>  fluid_adriver.c
1>     Creating library .\Release/fluidsynth.lib and object .\Release/fluidsynth.exp
1>fluid_voice.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_add referenced in function _new_fluid_voice
1>fluid_chan.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_add
1>fluid_hash.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_add
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_add
1>fluid_tuning.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_add
1>fluid_chan.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_compare_and_exchange referenced in function _fluid_channel_set_sfont_bank_prog
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_compare_and_exchange
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_winmidi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_cmd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_thread_functions_for_glib_use
1>fluid_cmd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_get_mutex_impl referenced in function _fluid_server_add_client
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_get_mutex_impl
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_get_mutex_impl
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_get_mutex_impl
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_winmidi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_cmd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__g_threads_got_initialized
1>fluid_cmd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_init referenced in function _new_fluid_server
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_init
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_init
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_init
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init referenced in function _fluid_synth_cc_LOCAL
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_winmidi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_cmd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_init
1>fluid_event.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_free referenced in function __fluid_evt_heap_free
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_free
1>fluid_seq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_mutex_free
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_log referenced in function _new_fluid_str_setting
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_tuning.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_event_queue.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_filerenderer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_hash.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_midi_router.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_log
1>fluid_hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_int_exchange_and_add referenced in function _fluid_hashtable_unref
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_free referenced in function _delete_fluid_settings
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_free
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_unlock referenced in function _fluid_settings_get_type
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_unlock
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_lock referenced in function _fluid_settings_get_type
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_lock
1>fluid_settings.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_init referenced in function _new_fluid_settings
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _g_static_rec_mutex_init
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_private_free referenced in function _delete_fluid_synth
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_self referenced in function _fluid_synth_alloc_voice
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_private_set referenced in function _fluid_synth_tuning_iteration_start
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_private_get referenced in function _fluid_synth_tuning_iteration_next
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_atomic_pointer_compare_and_exchange referenced in function _fluid_synth_get_event_queue
1>fluid_synth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_static_private_init referenced in function _new_fluid_synth
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_get_current_time referenced in function _fluid_curtime
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_clear_error referenced in function _new_fluid_thread
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_create_full referenced in function _new_fluid_thread
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_thread_join referenced in function _fluid_thread_join
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_usleep referenced in function _fluid_timer_run
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__recv@16 referenced in function _fluid_istream_gets
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__send@16 referenced in function _fluid_ostream_printf
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function _fluid_socket_close
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 referenced in function _fluid_server_socket_run
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__inet_ntoa@4 referenced in function _fluid_server_socket_run
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__accept@12 referenced in function _fluid_server_socket_run
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__listen@8 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htonl@4 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>fluid_sys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function _new_fluid_server_socket
1>../fluidsynth.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 38 unresolved externals
3>------ Build started: Project: fluidsynth, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>  fluid_aufile.c
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth\.\Release\fluidsynth.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>  fluid_chan.c
2>  fluid_chorus.c
3>  fluidsynth.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth\.\Release\fluidsynth.exe
2>  fluid_cmd.c
2>  fluid_conv.c
2>  fluid_defsfont.c
2>  fluid_dll.c
2>  fluid_dsound.c
2>  fluid_dsp_float.c
2>  fluid_event.c
2>  fluid_event_queue.c
2>  fluid_filerenderer.c
2>  fluid_gen.c
2>  fluid_hash.c
2>  fluid_list.c
2>  fluid_mdriver.c
2>  fluid_midi.c
2>  fluid_midi_router.c
2>  fluid_mod.c
2>  Generating Code...
2>  Compiling...
2>  fluid_ramsfont.c
2>  fluid_rev.c
2>  fluid_seq.c
2>  fluid_seqbind.c
2>  fluid_settings.c
2>  fluid_synth.c
2>  fluid_sys.c
2>  fluid_tuning.c
2>  fluid_voice.c
2>  fluid_winmidi.c
2>  Generating Code...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1151,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth_lib\.\Release\fluidsynth_lib.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth_lib.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
2>  fluidsynth_lib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.1\winbuild\fluidsynth_lib\.\Release\fluidsynth_lib.lib
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What version of glibc do you have? All the missing external symbols are atomic/mutex functions that are in glibc 2.4 and newer.

Comment: Sorry, I have solve for glib, gthread, etc part by link the *.lib in project properties but left is the winsock library. Where do I actually download?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have already resolved most of your problems, and are just missing the winsock stuff.

You need to install the [Windows Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx), which will install a lot of libraries. In the install location's lib directory will be the file `ws2_32.lib`, which is the Winsock2 library you want to link against.

Comment: So the SDK does not supported XP SP2 but SP3? Will WS2 affected for SP2? I have an issue with fluidsynth (compiled from QSynth) which get no sound from Windows XP, hopefully, anyone has the solution to get it work!

Answer (score 7):

You need to link to the ws2_32.lib file, which, as birryree mentions, is a Winsock2 library. However, if you don't know how to link this in, here are the instructions as outlined in [this MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/7596268f-8b4e-4008-9602-8e3cc4f4f0ea):

> In your project properties:
>
> Configuration Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.

Then add ws2_32.lib to the semi-colon separated list.